# iPhone: How to play a sound at a particular time?

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, nstimer

I have written the following code:

```
-(void)runTimer
{
    myTicker=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    myTicker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.00 target:self selector:@selector(vibrate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)showActivity
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter =
                  [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
        [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
         [timerLabel setText:[formatter stringFromDate:date]];
}
-(void) vibrate{
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

}
```

I want to play an audio file instead of vibrating the iPhone. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check **Apple's sample project [BubbleLevel](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/BubbleLevel/index.html)**. You want the SoundEffect.h and SoundEffect.m into your project and then just call:

```
mySound = [[SoundEffect alloc]
    initWithContentsOfFile:[mainBundle pathForResource:@"mySound"
    ofType:@"aif"]];
[mySound play];
```

**Warning:** I was able to play only AIF sounds converted via iTunes. Anything else failed, including CAF files. In short: import your whatever sound into iTunes (drag'n'drop), change export to AIF format and then export the file.

Answer (score 1):

Tangential to the main question but the method called by the timer selector should be of the form...

```
-(void) aribtaryMethodName:(NSTimer *) theTimer;
```

...or it may not be called properly. It's selector should look like this:

```
myTicker=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(aribtaryMethodName:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: +1 even thought not answer to the actual question, but an important fix to presented code to make it work. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Assume you have a `.caf` file, you can play it with

```
SystemSoundID sound_id;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(NSURL_of_your_caf_file, &sound_id);
...
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound_id);
```

To play music you may want to use `AVAudioPlayer` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. See AVAudioPlayer class.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)slider1Changed:(id)sender
{
    [timer invalidate];
    float sliderValue=slider1.value;
    int totalSecond=(int)sliderValue;
    time=totalSecond;
    int sec= totalSecond %60;
    int min= (totalSecond -sec)/60;
    sliderValue=(float)totalSecond;
    runTime.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%.2d",min,sec];
    [slider1 setValue:sliderValue];
    timer =   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerChanged) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    // to play the audio from particular time duration
    [player setCurrentTime:totalSecond];
}

-(void)timerChanged
{
   int totalSecond=[player duration];

   float slider1Time=(float)time;
   if (time <= totalSecond) {
      int sec= time %60;
      int min= (time -sec)/60;
      runTime.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%.2d",min,sec];
      [slider1 setValue:slider1Time];
   }
   else
   {
      [player stop];
      [timer invalidate];
   }
   time +=1;

}
```